# Git bash/zip file

Tags: zip, git-bash

I am trying to get into coding world and have this zip file that I need to access to play a game and learn commands. But when I click right click it doesn't show "here git bash". It does show for other files but not for zip files. Have been searching for the answer for two days now, but no luck. I have zip and unzip in git bash bin, but something is obviously wrong. If anyone can help, it will be very much appreciated. Thx

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are there any screenshots you can provide regarding an error message or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

I see Open `Git bash here` only for *folders*, not files (`.zip` or otherwise)

A right-click on a zip file should show you an option to uncompress it if you have installed a third-party tool like [Peazip](https://peazip.github.io/).
But Git bash would not be involved.

Not unless you right-click on the parent folder of the zip file, open a bash, and type `unzip your.zip`.

Comment: I am forever grateful to you for your comment. It was huge help. Thx

Comment: @Amk Thank you for your feedback. Glad to have been of assistance.